# Hiding and showing elements with jQuery flickers in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, animation

I am trying to make a simple animation with jQuery which works absolutely fine in Firefox but it flickers in Chrome and Edge, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjefro9m/3/), and here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxes-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box:first-child {
  background: pink;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: skyblue;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: gold;
}

.box.hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  $('#shadow').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  $('#shadow').hide();
});
```

I've dug up a few questions on SO but none of them answered how to get rid of the flicker.

Comment: why not do a seperate hover for your shadow so it shows on boxes wrapper hover

Comment: cuz I need to know which child triggered the hover so I can add a class to it

Comment: Actually having looked at your code, it is not possible to do what you want as if you do hide the overlay (which is what is causing the flicker), there is no way to hover another box and the non hovered boxes are behind the overlay

Comment: it doesn't work either just tried it

Comment: Scrap that last comment, I have a solution that is a mixture of css and that will work - bit of a hack but probably the best you could hope for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that your overlay is covering the non hovered boxes so it currently needs to disappear in order to hover the others.

The flash is caused by the space between your boxes - as soon as the mouse leaves, the overlay is hidden.

In order to get around this you will need a mixture of css and move the hover for the overlay to the box wrapper (comments in code):

```js
// remove overlay from this:
$('.box').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

// add this:
$('#boxes-wrapper').hover(function() {
  $('#shadow').show();
}, function() {
  $('#shadow').hide();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#boxes-wrapper {
  float: left;
  /*this makes the wrapper the same width as the boxes, you may need to add a clear fix after this*/
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.box:first-child {
  background: pink;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: skyblue;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: gold;
}
.box.hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}
#shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* add the following - means that the mouse hover will "go through" the overlay */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome but when I applied it to my project it still doesn't work : (

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your updated code to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/